# Set environment variable while referencing another

Tags: shell, docker

I'm trying to set an environment variable in a docker container and have it persist.

Running `ENV PATH=${PATH}:${HOME}/my_dir`

Results in `:/my_dir` being appended to the path, which is not what was intended.

However `PATH=${PATH}:/home/my_user/my_dir` correctly appends `:/home/my_user/my_dir` to the path.

What must be changed to avoid typing the absolute path?

Comment: Suggestion: install software in `/usr/bin` or another directory that's already on `$PATH`.  Don't really worry about `$HOME`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`${HOME}` is set by shell, when you build docker image with `ENV`, no shell there, so the value certainly be empty.

Try next:

```
ENV PATH=${PATH}:~/my_dir
```

`~` will be interpreted as `HOME` in container run time.